# How to get the the Schama.TableName in EF 6 database-first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I'm using EF 6 database-first..
I use this method to get the name of the table:

```
private static string GetTableName(ObjectContext context, Type entityType)
        {
            string entityTypeName = entityType.Name;

            EntityContainer container = context.MetadataWorkspace.GetEntityContainer(context.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace);
            string tableName = (from meta in container.BaseEntitySets
                                where meta.ElementType.Name == entityTypeName
                                select meta.Name).First();
            return tableName;
        }
```

but it only returns the table name, I have 5 schemas in the database, every schema corresponds to a separate `DbContext`, so it might have identical names with different schema. So I need to return the full name of the table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically you need `Table` and `Schema` properties of the `EntitySet` class. Unfortunately they are correctly populated only for the *storage* model, so in order to find it, you'll need to go through several model mappings.

Here is a sample method based on (in fact part of) the excellent post [EF6.1 Get Mapping Between Properties and Columns`](https://romiller.com/2015/08/05/ef6-1-get-mapping-between-properties-and-columns/) by Rowan Miller:

```
static EntitySet GetStorageEntitySet(ObjectContext objectContext, Type clrEntityType)
{ 
    var metadata = objectContext.MetadataWorkspace;

    // Get the part of the model that contains info about the actual CLR types
    var objectItemCollection = ((ObjectItemCollection)metadata.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.OSpace));

    // Get the entity type from the model that maps to the CLR type
    var entityType = metadata
            .GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace)
                  .Single(e => objectItemCollection.GetClrType(e) == clrEntityType);

    // Get the entity set that uses this entity type
    var entitySet = metadata
        .GetItems<EntityContainer>(DataSpace.CSpace)
              .Single()
              .EntitySets
              .Single(s => s.ElementType.Name == entityType.Name);

    // Find the mapping between conceptual and storage model for this entity set
    var mapping = metadata.GetItems<EntityContainerMapping>(DataSpace.CSSpace)
        .Single()
        .EntitySetMappings
        .Single(s => s.EntitySet == entitySet);

    // Find the storage entity set (table) that the entity is mapped
    return mapping
        .EntityTypeMappings.Single()
        .Fragments.Single()
        .StoreEntitySet;
}
```

Sample usage in your case:

```
private static string GetTableName(ObjectContext context, Type entityType)
{
    var entitySet = GetStorageEntitySet(context, entityType);
    return entitySet.Schema + "." + entitySet.Table;
}
```

**Update:** It turns out that there are differences between Code First and Database First in regard to `EntitySet` `Table` and `Name` properties, so to get the table name generically I would suggest using:

```
var tableName = entitySet.Table ?? entitySet.Name;
```

Comment: Do you mean `entitySet.Name` ? because `entitySet.Table` returns `null`

Comment: I'm using your code, it returns the schema name correctly, but the table name is null!

Comment: Ok, you are right, there seem to be difference between Code First and Database First. You can use the `Name` property in your case or more generally the code from the update.

Comment: I think If I gave the mapped entity different name it will return that new name!

Comment: I already tried it with edmx model and it really returns the table name. Actually I found another post by the same author (which was a member of the EF team btw) which suggest the same - [EF6.1 Mapping Between Types & Tables](https://romiller.com/2014/04/08/ef6-1-mapping-between-types-tables/) - see `GetTableName` method implementation.