# How can one convert between an EF model's conceptual info and its store info at run-time, even when MSL is in a resource?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.4

In another post ([How can I extract the database table and column name for a property on an EF4 entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313008/how-can-i-extract-the-database-table-and-column-name-for-a-property-on-an-ef4-en/63760805#63760805)), I provided an answer (top of page) for extracting at run-time an Entity-Framework model's store info (*table/column*) from conceptual info (*entity/property-expression*). Usually, one doesn't need such functionality--but sometimes it's useful, like when one wants to add an additional index to an entity's table for a database created at run-time.

The ***drawback*** with my solution (see below) is that it requires that the MSL mapping info be in a separate file (i.e., the host project copies the metadata to the output path) or that its XML already be available. What if the MSL metadata is embedded as an *assembly resource*? (XElement methods can't resolve a "res://" path-name!) How does one get the mapping (or the XML for the mapping) then?

Any solution--whether it uses XML, metadata-workspace, or whatever--must work with projects targeted at pre-.NET 4.7 platforms (i.e., .NET 4.6.1), be able to work with *any* EF model (regardless of whether it's created Model-First, Database-First, or Code-First), and be capable of handling complex-property info (i.e., *Entity.ComplexProperty. ... .ComplexSubProperty.ScalarProperty*) as well as scalar-property info. Ideally, it should also work with DbContext-derived contexts (although an ObjectContext can be extracted from a DbContext) and be in VB.NET. (I'm currently using Visual Basic 2019 with EF 6.4, and my "host project" is targeted at .NET 4.6.1.)

For perspective, here is the code for my *existing* solution (remember the aforementioned limitations that I want to mitigate):

**Host code:** (For the XML sample given [see bottom], it returns table name "Locations" and column name "Address_Street" for the store information when given the entity "Location" and the property expression "Address.Street" [and the conceptual model name "SCTModel"]):

```
Dim MSL As MSLMappingAction = New MSLMappingAction(".\SCTModel.msl", "SCTModel")

Dim ConceptualInfo As MSLConceptualInfo = New MSLConceptualInfo With {.EntityName = "Location", .PropertyName = "Address.Street"}
Dim StoreInfo As MSLStoreInfo = MSL.ConceptualToStore(ConceptualInfo)
MessageBox.Show(StoreInfo.TableName & ": " & StoreInfo.ColumnName)
```

**Class code:**

```
Option Infer On
Imports System.Xml.Linq

''' <summary>
''' This class allows one to convert between an EF conceptual model's entity/property pair
''' and its database store's table/column pair.
''' </summary>
''' <remarks>It takes into account entity splitting and complex-property designations;
''' it DOES NOT take into account inherited properties
''' (in such a case, you should access the entity's base class)</remarks>
Public Class MSLMappingAction

'   private fields and routines
Private mmaMSLMapping As XElement
Private mmaModelName, mmaNamespace As String

Private Function FullElementName(ByVal ElementName As String) As String
'   pre-pend Namespace to ElementName
Return "{" & mmaNamespace & "}" & ElementName
End Function

Private Sub ValidateParams(ByVal MappingXML As XElement, Byval ModelName As String)
'   verify that model name is specified
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(ModelName) Then
    Throw New EntityException("Entity model name is not given!")
End If
'   verify that we're using C-S space
If MappingXML.@Space <> "C-S" Then
    Throw New MetadataException("XML is not C-S mapping data!")
End If
'   get Namespace and set private variables
mmaNamespace = MappingXML.@xmlns
mmaMSLMapping = MappingXML : mmaModelName = ModelName
End Sub

Private Function IsSequenceEmpty(Items As IEnumerable(Of XElement)) As Boolean
'   determine if query result is empty
Return _
    Items Is Nothing OrElse Items.Count = 0
End Function

'   properties
''' <summary>
''' Name of conceptual entity model
''' </summary>
''' <returns>Conceptual-model String</returns>
''' <remarks>Model name can only be set in constructor</remarks>
Public ReadOnly Property EntityModelName() As String
Get
    Return mmaModelName
End Get
End Property

''' <summary>
''' Name of mapping namespace
''' </summary>
''' <returns>Namespace String of C-S mapping layer</returns>
''' <remarks>This value is determined when the XML mapping
''' is first parsed in the constructor</remarks>
Public ReadOnly Property MappingNamespace() As String
Get
    Return mmaNamespace
End Get
End Property

'   constructors
''' <summary>
''' Get C-S mapping information for an entity model (with XML tree)
''' </summary>
''' <param name="MappingXML">XML mapping tree</param>
''' <param name="ModelName">Conceptual-model name</param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Sub New(ByVal MappingXML As XElement, ByVal ModelName As String)
ValidateParams(MappingXML, ModelName)
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Get C-S mapping information for an entity model (with XML file)
''' </summary>
''' <param name="MSLFile">MSL mapping file</param>
''' <param name="ModelName">Conceptual-model name</param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Sub New(ByVal MSLFile As String, ByVal ModelName As String)
Dim MappingXML As XElement = XElement.Load(MSLFile)
ValidateParams(MappingXML, ModelName)
End Sub

'   methods
''' <summary>
''' Get C-S mapping infomration for an entity model (with XML String)
''' </summary>
''' <param name="XMLString">XML mapping String</param>
''' <param name="ModelName">Conceptual-model name</param>
''' <returns></returns>
Public Shared Function Parse(ByVal XMLString As String, ByVal ModelName As String)
Return New MSLMappingAction(XElement.Parse(XMLString), ModelName)
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Convert conceptual entity/property information into store table/column information
''' </summary>
''' <param name="ConceptualInfo">Conceptual-model data
''' (.EntityName = entity expression String, .PropertyName = property expression String)</param>
''' <returns>Store data (.TableName = table-name String, .ColumnName = column-name String)</returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Function ConceptualToStore(ByVal ConceptualInfo As MSLConceptualInfo) As MSLStoreInfo
Dim StoreInfo As New MSLStoreInfo
With ConceptualInfo
    '   prepare to query XML
    If Not .EntityName.Contains(".") Then
        '   make sure entity name is fully qualified
        .EntityName = mmaModelName & "." & .EntityName
    End If
    '   separate property names if there's complex-type nesting
    Dim Properties() As String = .PropertyName.Split(".")
    '   get relevant entity mapping
    Dim MappingInfo As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = _                 
        (From mi In mmaMSLMapping.Descendants(FullElementName("EntityTypeMapping")) _
            Where mi.@TypeName = "IsTypeOf(" & .EntityName & ")" _
                OrElse mi.@TypeName = .EntityName _
         Select mi)
    '   make sure entity is in model
    If IsSequenceEmpty(MappingInfo) Then
        Throw New EntityException("Entity """ & .EntityName & """ was not found!")
    End If
    '   get mapping fragments
    Dim MappingFragments As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = _
        (From mf In MappingInfo.Descendants(FullElementName("MappingFragment")) _
         Select mf)
    '   make sure there's at least 1 fragment
    If IsSequenceEmpty(MappingFragments) Then
        Throw New EntityException("Entity """ & .EntityName & """ was not mapped!")
    End If
    '   search each mapping fragment for the desired property
    For Each MappingFragment In MappingFragments
        '   get physical table for this fragment
        StoreInfo.TableName = MappingFragment.@StoreEntitySet
        '   search property expression chain
        Dim PropertyMapping As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = {MappingFragment}
        '   parse complex property info (if any)
        For index = 0 To UBound(Properties) - 1
            '   go down 1 level
            Dim ComplexPropertyName = Properties(index)
            PropertyMapping = _
                (From pm In PropertyMapping.Elements(FullElementName("ComplexProperty")) _
                    Where pm.@Name = ComplexPropertyName)
            '   verify that the property specified for this level exists
            If IsSequenceEmpty(PropertyMapping) Then
                Exit For 'go to next fragment if not
            End If
        Next index
        '   property not found? try next fragment
        If IsSequenceEmpty(PropertyMapping) Then
            Continue For
        End If
        '   parse scalar property info
        Dim ScalarPropertyName = Properties(UBound(Properties))
        Dim ColumnName As String = _
            (From pm In PropertyMapping.Elements(FullElementName("ScalarProperty")) _
                Where pm.@Name = ScalarPropertyName _
                Select CN = pm.@ColumnName).FirstOrDefault
        '   verify that scalar property exists
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ColumnName) Then
            '   yes? return (exit) with column info
            StoreInfo.ColumnName = ColumnName : Return StoreInfo
        End If
    Next MappingFragment
    '   property wasn't found
    Throw New EntityException("Property """ & .PropertyName _
        & """ of entity """ & .EntityName & """ was not found!")
End With
End Function
End Class

''' <summary>
''' Conceptual-model entity and property information  
''' </summary>
Public Structure MSLConceptualInfo
''' <summary>
''' Name of entity in conceptual model
''' </summary>
''' <value>Entity expression String</value>
''' <remarks>EntityName may or may not be fully qualified (i.e., "ModelName.EntityName");
''' when a mapping method is called by the MSLMappingAction class, the conceptual model's
''' name and a period will be pre-pended if it's omitted</remarks>
Public Property EntityName As String
''' <summary>
''' Name of property in entity
''' </summary>
''' <value>Property expression String</value>
''' <remarks>PropertyName may be either a stand-alone scalar property or a scalar property
''' within 1 or more levels of complex-type properties; in the latter case, it MUST be fully
''' qualified (i.e., "ComplexPropertyName.InnerComplexPropertyName.ScalarPropertyName")</remarks>
Public Property PropertyName As String
End Structure

''' <summary>
''' Database-store table and column information
''' </summary>
Public Structure MSLStoreInfo
''' <summary>
''' Name of table in database
''' </summary>
Public Property TableName As String
''' <summary>
''' Name of column in database table
''' </summary>
Public Property ColumnName As String
End Structure
```

Here's the *sample* XML -- which I load from the ".\SCTModel.msl" file in the code above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Mapping Space="C-S" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/mapping/cs">
  <EntityContainerMapping StorageEntityContainer="SCTModelStoreContainer" CdmEntityContainer="SocialContactsTracker">
    <EntitySetMapping Name="SocialContacts">
      <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(SCTModel.SocialContact)">
        <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="SocialContacts">
          <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="DateAdded" ColumnName="DateAdded" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="Information" ColumnName="Information" />
          <ComplexProperty Name="DefaultAssociations" TypeName="SCTModel.DefaultAssociations">
            <ScalarProperty Name="DefaultLocationID" ColumnName="DefaultAssociations_DefaultLocationID" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="DefaultEmailID" ColumnName="DefaultAssociations_DefaultEmailID" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="DefaultPhoneNumberID" ColumnName="DefaultAssociations_DefaultPhoneNumberID" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="DefaultWebsiteID" ColumnName="DefaultAssociations_DefaultWebsiteID" />
          </ComplexProperty>
          <ScalarProperty Name="Picture" ColumnName="Picture" />
        </MappingFragment>
      </EntityTypeMapping>
      <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(SCTModel.Person)">
        <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="SocialContacts_Person">
          <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="DateOfBirth" ColumnName="DateOfBirth" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="FirstName" ColumnName="FirstName" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="LastName" ColumnName="LastName" />
        </MappingFragment>
      </EntityTypeMapping>
      <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(SCTModel.Organization)">
        <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="SocialContacts_Organization">
          <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="Name" ColumnName="Name" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="DateOfCreation" ColumnName="DateOfCreation" />
        </MappingFragment>
      </EntityTypeMapping>
    </EntitySetMapping>
    <EntitySetMapping Name="Locations">
      <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(SCTModel.Location)">
        <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Locations">
          <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="City" ColumnName="City" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="State" ColumnName="State" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="ZIP" ColumnName="ZIP" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="Country" ColumnName="Country" />
          <ComplexProperty Name="Address" TypeName="SCTModel.Address">
            <ScalarProperty Name="Street" ColumnName="Address_Street" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="Apartment" ColumnName="Address_Apartment" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="HouseNumber" ColumnName="Address_HouseNumber" />
          </ComplexProperty>
        </MappingFragment>
      </EntityTypeMapping>
    </EntitySetMapping>
    <EntitySetMapping Name="PhoneNumbers">
      <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(SCTModel.PhoneNumber)">
        <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="PhoneNumbers">
          <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="Number" ColumnName="Number" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="PhoneType" ColumnName="PhoneType" />
        </MappingFragment>
      </EntityTypeMapping>
    </EntitySetMapping>
    <EntitySetMapping Name="Emails">
      <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(SCTModel.Email)">
        <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Emails">
          <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="DomainName" ColumnName="DomainName" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="UserName" ColumnName="UserName" />
        </MappingFragment>
      </EntityTypeMapping>
    </EntitySetMapping>
    <EntitySetMapping Name="Websites">
      <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(SCTModel.Website)">
        <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Websites">
          <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
          <ScalarProperty Name="URL" ColumnName="URL" />
        </MappingFragment>
      </EntityTypeMapping>
    </EntitySetMapping>
    <AssociationSetMapping Name="SocialContactWebsite" TypeName="SCTModel.SocialContactWebsite" StoreEntitySet="SocialContactWebsite">
      <EndProperty Name="SocialContact">
        <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="SocialContacts_Id" />
      </EndProperty>
      <EndProperty Name="Website">
        <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Websites_Id" />
      </EndProperty>
    </AssociationSetMapping>
    <AssociationSetMapping Name="SocialContactPhoneNumber" TypeName="SCTModel.SocialContactPhoneNumber" StoreEntitySet="SocialContactPhoneNumber">
      <EndProperty Name="SocialContact">
        <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="SocialContacts_Id" />
      </EndProperty>
      <EndProperty Name="PhoneNumber">
        <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="PhoneNumbers_Id" />
      </EndProperty>
    </AssociationSetMapping>
    <AssociationSetMapping Name="SocialContactEmail" TypeName="SCTModel.SocialContactEmail" StoreEntitySet="SocialContactEmail">
      <EndProperty Name="SocialContact">
        <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="SocialContacts_Id" />
      </EndProperty>
      <EndProperty Name="Email">
        <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Emails_Id" />
      </EndProperty>
    </AssociationSetMapping>
    <AssociationSetMapping Name="SocialContactLocation" TypeName="SCTModel.SocialContactLocation" StoreEntitySet="SocialContactLocation">
      <EndProperty Name="SocialContact">
        <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="SocialContacts_Id" />
      </EndProperty>
      <EndProperty Name="Location">
        <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Locations_Id" />
      </EndProperty>
    </AssociationSetMapping>
  </EntityContainerMapping>
</Mapping>
```

Once again, ***my issue*** is getting store info (*table/column*) from conceptual info (*entity/property-expression*) when the MSL mapping info is embedded in the project as a resource (i.e., "res://SCTModel.msl")

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45398675/how-to-get-the-the-schama-tablename-in-ef-6-database-first/45399754#45399754 and the linked https://romiller.com/2015/08/05/ef6-1-get-mapping-between-properties-and-columns/

Comment: @Ivan Stoev -- The https://romiller.com/2015/08/05/ef6-1-get-mapping-between-properties-and-columns/ example only works with simple properties--and some of my entities use complex properties. How does one modify the code in the example to get the column name for a complex-property expression (i.e., "Address.Street.HouseNumber" [of, say, entity LocationDetail]--dot-delimited all the way down from a "surface" property to an underlying scalar one)? (It appears that the needed change would be in the last line of the method--but I'm not fluent with metadata workspaces.)

Comment: BTW, any example MUST be compatible with .NET 4.6.1, and must work with ANY model--be it Model First, Code First, or Database First! And remember what I said about COMPLEX properties.